# List records grouped by category name

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I am having some problems, trying to get data from my database, and show it correctly. I have a layout, where I have two "lists", where I can add rows to each lists. I can add multiple rows to each list.

I want to display the output, so the first list, along with all it's row is showed first and then the second list, along with it's rows.

Currently, it is showed like this:

```
    LIST #1
 -- row inside list #1 -- 
 -- row inside list #1 --

    LIST #2
 -- row inside list #2 --
```

Currently, it is displaying like this:

```
    LIST #1
 -- row inside list #1 -- 
    LIST #2
 -- row inside list #2 --
    LIST #1
 -- row inside list #1 --
```

Below is a visual:

[image: Problem visualized]

This is my selection in PHP:

```
    $driving=$dbh->prepare("SELECT 
    driving_lists.id,
    driving_lists.list_id,
    driving_lists.date,
    driving_lists.list_name,
    driving_list_shipments.*
FROM
    driving_lists
        LEFT JOIN driving_list_shipments ON driving_lists.list_id = driving_list_shipments.list_id

    ");
    $driving->execute();
```

And the output script:

```
foreach( $driving as $row){
                echo "<pre>";
                echo $row["list_name"];
                echo "<br />";
                echo $row["reference"];
                echo "</pre>";
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Luckily you are using PDO which already has this functionality, that can do exactly what you want - group the data based on some column.

[PDO can group results into the nested arrays](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP), based on the first column in the field list. So you need to put your list id as the first column in the field list, and then get all rows using `fetchAll()` using aforementioned fetch mode:

```
$sql = "SELECT dl.list_id, dl.id, dl.date, dl.list_name, dls.*
  FROM driving_lists dl LEFT JOIN
     driving_list_shipments dls
 ON dl.list_id = dls.list_id
 ORDER BY dl.list_id";

$driving = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

and now you get a neat nested array where rows are grouped by list id!

To output neatly you have to use two nested foreach operators

```
foreach ($driving as $list_id => $list_data)
{
     echo $list_data[0]['list_name']."<br />\n"; 
     foreach ($list_data as $row)
     {
         echo "whatever";
     }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty sweet! Works like a charm. However, just a question regarding the double nested foreach statement - how does this affect the performance?

Comment: just a follow up question - how can I use the data from the table in the first foreach statement? For example, how do I print dl.list_name value in the first foreach statement?

Comment: Yes, sure. There is always at least one row, so you can safely address it like `$list_data[0]['list_name']`

Answer (score 0):

If you run a SQL query and you want the results in a particular order, then *ALWAYS* include an `order by` clause.

In your case, you seem to want:

```
SELECT dl.id, dl.list_id, dl.date, dl.list_name,
       dls.*
FROM driving_lists dl LEFT JOIN
     driving_list_shipments dls
     ON dl.list_id = dls.list_id
ORDER BY dl.list_id;
```

I assume that `list_id` is what you mean by `list_id`.

I should note that you have `list_id` appearing twice in the `SELECT`, because it is in both tables.  You should probably explicitly list the columns you want from both tables, and avoid redundant columns.

Comment: This sort the list correctly, however it is not merging all the rows inside the list. Now, it displays a LIST # for each row, inside that list. I want to merge the list rows, inside each list.

Comment: You should do that "merging" at the application level.

Comment: I am not quite sure where you see list_id twice in the select? I only see "list_id" and "id"

Comment: @oliverbj . . . It is in `driving_list_shipments` as well.