# PHP / MySQL: Display all rows matching specific value in column

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo

**SOLVED**
[Sloan Trasher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43605188/6396604) worked great. I added another set of if-statements that checks the *subcat_id* and prints the right header before the according .

```
if($curr_sub_cat != $row['subcat_id']) {
  if($curr_sub_cat != '') {
    echo "</div>\n";
  }
  $curr_sub_cat = $row['subcat_id'];
  if($curr_sub_cat == '1') {
    echo "<h1 class='anchor' id='smartphones'>Smartphones</h1>";
    echo "<div class='flexed-boxes'>\n";
  }
  if($curr_sub_cat == '2') {
    echo "<h1 class='anchor' id='tablets'>Tablets</h1>";
    echo "<div class='flexed-boxes'>\n";
  }
}
```

**Original question**
I have a database table which looks something like this:

```
dev_id  dev_name         cat_id  subcat_id
```

```
1       Apple iPhone 6   1       1
2       Apple iPhone 6s  1       1
3       Apple iPad Air   1       2
```

*dev_id* is the primary key, *cat_id* is different for each brand (Apple = 1, Samsung = 2 etc.) and *subcat_id* indicates if the device is either a phone (1) or a tablet (2).

I want to echo all the devices of one brand which have *subcat_id == 1* assigned to them in one list with the header *Smartphones*. All the rows where the column *subcat_id == 2* need to go in a list below that one with the header *Tablets*. Both lists need to be sorted by the primary key in ascending order.

Using `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` and `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` like this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT subcat_id,dev_id FROM devices WHERE cat_id='$cat_id' ORDER BY dev_id";
 $data = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Prints the array with all the (in this case Apple) devices nicely:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 6
        [6] => 7
        [7] => 8
        [8] => 9
        [9] => 10
        [10] => 11
        [11] => 12
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13
        [1] => 14
        [2] => 15
        [3] => 16
        [4] => 17
        [5] => 18
    )
)
```

If I implement a for-loop as follows:

```
 $cat_name_lower=strtolower($cat_name);
 $dev_name_ul=str_replace(array("$cat_name "," "),array("","_"),$row_all_dev['dev_name']);

 foreach ($data as $dev => $dev_data)
 {
   echo "<div class='flexed-boxes'>
        ";
     foreach ($dev_data as $row)
     {
       echo "<a class='singlebox trpl' href='/devices/".$cat_name_lower."/smartphone_details.php?dev_name=".$dev_name_ul."'>
              <img class='singlebox-media' src='".$cat_name_lower."/img/".$row_all_dev['dev_img']."' alt='".$row_all_dev['dev_name']."'>
              <span class='singlebox-header'>".$row_all_dev['dev_name']."</span>
            </a>
            ";
     }
   echo "</div>";
 }
```

I get the first entry  in the table (the iPhone 6, which in my actual database has a dev_id of 6) printed times 18 - [picture for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXUJM.png). However, I want the rows [to show up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHmHn.png) (the second row in the picture contains the iPhone 6, 6 Plus and 6s, which happen to have the same picture).
To me it looks like the for loop is iterated correctly but the internal array pointer isn't advanced by one? Where am I going wrong?

*This question is a follow-up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000835/php-mysql-select-and-echo-row-based-on-column-value)*

Comment: What is $row_all_dev? If you want the data in a column of the row in the loop, refer to $row['column_name'].

Comment: At the top of my HTML document I load all the rows containing the info about all the devices of the currently displayed brand into the variable $row_all_dev. I know it's ugly, but since that variable contains all the data of all the devices displayed on the page, I can pull the images from it.

Comment: Then why the foreach? Inside the loop you do not use the $row value, which is where you will find the specific value for the "row".

Comment: It seemed to me that I needed a for-loop to do it in a clean way, but if there's an easier way to achieve my goal please tell me. I based my code on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41263854/6396604). No explanation about $row was given there but now you say it, the data from my query does indeed get loaded into $row. If I edit $sql to include dev_name, dev_id and edit the echo to load from $row instead of $row_all_dev, it simply echoes the numbers 1-18 which actually seems like expected since an array only contains numbers. I however need the related data, not numbers.

Comment: Anyone? I'm still stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "";
$sql .= "SELECT\n";
$sql .= "   subcat_id,\n";
$sql .= "   dev_id,\n";
$sql .= "   dev_img,\n";    //  Not sure if that column exists in the table???
$sql .= "   dev_name\n";
$sql .= "FROM devices\n";
$sql .= "WHERE cat_id='$cat_id'\n";
$sql .= "ORDER BY subcat_id, dev_id";

$data = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();

$cat_name_lower = strtolower($cat_name);

echo "<div class='flexed-boxes'>\n";
$curr_sub_cat = '';
foreach($data as $row_no => $row) {
    $dev_name_ul = str_replace(array("$cat_name "," "),array("","_"),$row['dev_name']);

    if($curr_sub_cat != $row['subcat_id']) {
        if($curr_sub_cat != '') {
            echo "</div>\n";
            echo "<div class='flexed-boxes'>\n";
        }
        $curr_sub_cat = $row['subcat_id'];
    }
    echo "<a class='singlebox trpl' href='/devices/".$cat_name_lower."/smartphone_details.php?dev_name=".$dev_name_ul."'>
              <img class='singlebox-media' src='".$cat_name_lower."/img/".$row["dev_img"]."' alt='".$row['dev_name']."'>
              <span class='singlebox-header'>".$row['dev_name']."</span>
            </a>\n";
}
echo "</div>\n";
//  echo "<p>\$data:<pre>".print_r($data,true)."</pre></p>\n";
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and while this code does make the table data display in a correct manner, it doesn't put the smartphones (subcat_id == 1) in a different <div> than the tablets (subcat_id == 2). I also don't see a way how I can accomplish it by editing the code you wrote.

Comment: That's pretty easy. Just do change detect on the sub-cat id and close/open the div when it changes. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help; I marked your post as the answer and updated my OP. With a few minor edits I was able to print the right headers at the beginning of each <div>. By the way, there's a small error in the code which causes an empty <div> to be inserted at the top of the page. Any idea how to stop this from happening without setting _$curr_sub_cat_ to _1_?

Comment: See the updated answer. Basically, it ignores the first sub cat change.

Comment: Of course. I integrated it in my piece of code in the OP. That extra check also made   echo "<div class='flexed-boxes'>\n";   outside the for-loop redundant.

Comment: It shouldn't -- you'll need the start div before the foreach. Note that it closes a div and then opens the next. But I see what you did, making the ending div conditional.

Answer (score -1):

Try this and show the result in your question. It's not the answer yet, but will provide the info needed to give you an answer.

```
$sql = "";
$sql .= "SELECT\n";
$sql .= "   subcat_id,\n";
$sql .= "   dev_id,\n";
$sql .= "   dev_name\n";
$sql .= "FROM devices\n";
$sql .= "WHERE cat_id='$cat_id'\n";
$sql .= "ORDER BY subcat_id, dev_id";

$data = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();

echo "<p>\$data:<pre>".print_r($data,true)."</pre></p>\n";
```

Comment: That's a very pretty print. I pasted the result here: https://pastebin.com/cZVi5E9L. It's basically all the information I gave in the opening post, listed in a nice array.

Comment: Where are you getting $cat_name?

Comment: Whoever down-voted, please offer a reason why in the comments.... This answer was a way to get clarification from the OP.

Comment: The first thing in my <head> is the following code block: https://pastebin.com/qSztBC1v (this is where I referred to in my comment on Mar 31 at 15:12). Also, I don't know who downvoted your comment. It had already been downvoted when I first viewed the answer.